# How to work around "function template has already been defined" when using std::enable_if with constexpr method

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, constexpr, enable-if

When using a `constexpr` method as the argument of `std::enable_if_t`, old MSVC compilers complain about "function template has already been defined". G++ and newer MSVC compilers accept that. How I can make that work also with old MSCV compilers?

Example code:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename NumberType>
constexpr auto doBitCountsMatch(const int f_bitCount) -> bool {

  return (static_cast<int>(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(NumberType)) == f_bitCount);
}

template <typename NumberType, int bitCount>
auto test()
    -> std::enable_if_t<doBitCountsMatch<NumberType>(bitCount), NumberType> {
  std::cout << "Bit counts match." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

template <typename NumberType, int bitCount>
auto test()
    -> std::enable_if_t<!doBitCountsMatch<NumberType>(bitCount), NumberType> {
  std::cout << "Bit counts don't match." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

int main() {
  int number = 0;

  test<decltype(number), 32>();
  return 0;
}
```

And here in Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/15PnPhvo8: MSVC 19.14 rejects the code, MSVC 19.33 accepts it. Why do the old compilers reject the code?

Comment: *"Why do the old compilers reject the code?"* because of "bugs"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `std::enable_if_t` as template parameter instead:

```
template <typename NumberType, int bitCount,
          std::enable_if_t<doBitCountsMatch<NumberType>(bitCount), int> = 0>
auto test() -> NumberType
{
  std::cout << "Bit counts match." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

template <typename NumberType, int bitCount,
          std::enable_if_t<!doBitCountsMatch<NumberType>(bitCount), int> = 0>
auto test() -> NumberType
{
  std::cout << "Bit counts don't match." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GWP6qj6oz)

Comment: Cool that this works. But what is the difference?! Isn't my version with the return type also completely correct?!?!

Comment: Both are corrects. C++11/C++14 implementation were chaotic at start... Computation of signature seems done wrongly with that version of msvc.

Comment: I use `,bool> = true` instead of `,int> = 0`, not because it make a difference, but because it evokes "the clause is true".